# how to disable screen rotation in my Windows Phone 8 Application?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I try to disable screen rotation in my application because images are moving and it's not good. How can I disable to landscape ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what i understand from this question is that you need your WP8 app to be locked in one orientation. Disable landscape means you need the app to be in portrait mode, Assuming that the easiest way to do this is in your page, in XAML view set the following values in `phone:PhoneApplicationPage` tag

```
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
```

`SupportedOrientations` property has 3 values, `Portrait`, `Landscape`, `PortraitOrLandscape`. and `Orientation` property has `None`, `Landscape`, `LandscapeLeft`, `LandscapeRight`, `Portrait`, `PortraitUp` and `PortraitDown`. Choose as you need. In your case the above values should do it

Comment: Oh God!! I didn't realized it.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: :) glad i could help.. Please up vote. Note previous answer was for WP8.1